# Insert data into phpmyadmin table field automatically

Tags: defined

I have a table field "dealership name".. that I want to have automatically be populated with a specific name.  I thought I could do it through "as defined" in the actual table but that doesn't seem to be working.  As I'm search through the help fields.. it seems the only way to do it is with "update"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using PHP Cron Job will be useful to you